# Найти все входящие элементы в диапазоне python

Tags: python

Есть входные данные в виде строки (это всегда числа), которые к этому моменту превращаются в список.

```
    welcome = 'Пожалуйста, введите значения от 1 до 24 через запятую или одно число.\n' \
              + 'Пример: 1,2,3 или 24 или 4 5 6 или любой другой символ в качестве разделителя'
    print(welcome)
    outlets_input = input()
    print('Введенные данные: ', outlets_input)
    pattern_match = re.match(r'[^\D]+|^[\D]+|[\D]+$', outlets_input)
    if pattern_match:
        pattern_comma = re.sub(r"\D+", ' ', outlets_input)
        print('Лишние символы удалены. Вывод:', pattern_comma)
        print('Тип объекта', pattern_comma, type(pattern_comma))
        pattern_space = re.sub(r"\s+", '', pattern_comma)
        print('Пробелы удалены. Вывод:', pattern_space)
        print('Тип объекта', pattern_space, type(pattern_space))
        splitting_outlets = re.split(r"\D+", pattern_comma)
        print('Преобразование строки в список. Вывод:', splitting_outlets)
        print('Тип объекта', splitting_outlets, type(splitting_outlets))
        space = ''
        while space in splitting_outlets:
            splitting_outlets.remove('')
            print('Удаление пустых объектов. Вывод:', splitting_outlets)
        transform_outlets = list(map(int, splitting_outlets))
        print('Преобразование в отдельные числа. Вывод:', transform_outlets)
        print('Тип объекта', transform_outlets, type(transform_outlets))
        for list_range in list(range(1, 25)):
            if list_range in transform_outlets:
                print('Поиск совпадения в элементе номер', list_range)
                print('Найдено совпадение в элементе номер', list_range)
            # else:
            #     print('ERROOROR')
            #     raise SystemExit('Введенные данные не совпадают с условиями.')
        outlets = ','.join(str(e) for e in transform_outlets)
        print(outlets)
        return outlets
    else:
        outlets = outlets_input
        return outlets
```

Вывожу принты:

```
Пожалуйста, введите значения от 1 до 24 через запятую или одно число.
Пример: 1,2,3 или 24 или 4 5 6 или любой другой символ в качестве разделителя
0,1,2,3
Введенные данные:  0,1,2,3
Лишние символы удалены. Вывод: 0 1 2 3
Тип объекта 0 1 2 3 <class 'str'>
Пробелы удалены. Вывод: 0123
Тип объекта 0123 <class 'str'>
Преобразование строки в список. Вывод: ['0', '1', '2', '3']
Тип объекта ['0', '1', '2', '3'] <class 'list'>
Преобразование в отдельные числа. Вывод: [0, 1, 2, 3]
Тип объекта [0, 1, 2, 3] <class 'list'>
Поиск совпадения в элементе номер 1
Найдено совпадение в элементе номер 1
Поиск совпадения в элементе номер 2
Найдено совпадение в элементе номер 2
Поиск совпадения в элементе номер 3
Найдено совпадение в элементе номер 3
0,1,2,3
```

Если вводные данные корректны и проходят в рэндж от 1 до 24, то исполняем эту часть кода:

```
        outlets = ','.join(str(e) for e in transform_outlets)
        print(outlets)
        return outlets
```

Если хоть одно число выходит за рамки рэнджа, прерываем выполнение.

Использовать `set` я не могу, так как это не хэшируемый объект.

Comment: Ничего не понял. Мы вводим данные, делаем из них список и потом с этими же данными  сравниваем?

Comment: щас закину весь код

Comment: `set` -> `frozenset`.

Comment: можно уточнить, что вы в итоге хотите получить? вывести все цифры, найденные во введенной пользователем строке, которые не разделены каким-либа разделителем?

Comment: Это одна из многих проверок для авторизации на устройстве. Конфиг радиуса принимает значения только в формате [x,y,z], где "x,y,z" это номера управляемых розеток. 

  APC-Outlets = "1[1,3,5];"

Эта часть отвечает непосредственно за проверку введенных данных, чтобы конфиг не ломался и не приходилось все править руками.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень, очень сложно. Так проще: выделяем подстроки из цифр, отбрасываем пустые, непустые переводим в числа. Проверку правильности делаем через минимум и максимум:

```
import re

values = [int(t) for t in re.split(r'\D+', input()) if t]

if 1 <= min(values) and max(values) <= 24:
    print(*values, sep=',')
else:
    print('error')
```

Comment: Спасибо! 

Да, действительно, сложновато получилось. Завтра попробую Ваше предложение.